# Animate Scrolling to the Top 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

sorry for reposting this question again LOL

I want to make a scroll to the top animation link, like the link at the bottom of this website, http://www.thechrisellefactor.com/

The HTML for my home button is

```html
<div class="blog-pager" id="blog-pager">
<a class="home-link" href="http://YOURBLOG.blogspot.ca/">Home</a>
</div>
```

I've edited this code in my HTML to this

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
$('#blog-pager').on('click', function(){
    $("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
}); 
</script>
```

```html
<body>
    <div class='mobile-link-button' id='blog-pager-home-link'>
    <a class='home-link' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' value="go to top"><data:homeMsg/></a>
    </div>
  </body>
```

However this is still not working? What did I do wrong? Is it something in the jquery or html or both?

Comment: if you put `<a>` tag inside div the page will redirect just make two separate one to redirect link and one to scroll top

Answer (score 0):

im confused as to which HTML you're actually using, but for the second example there is no `#blog-pager`. if you switch it to `.home-link` it works fine:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/up88cq6n/)

Comment: So I would just at the javascript code before </head> in my HTML and modify the home link code by adding "value="go to top"" and it should work?

Comment: the value of the link is not going to make a difference. just make sure that your click event matches the class name

Comment: Alright, I think I got it. Where would I put the java code in my HTML? Within script tags right under "<div class='mobile-link-button' id='blog-pager-home-link'>
    <a class='home-link' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' value='go to top'><data:homeMsg/></a>
    </div>"?